# C++ error question: Expected Unqualified-id

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

public static void main (String[]args)
{
    int dozen=12;
    double PricePerDozen = 3.25;
    double PricePerEgg = 0.45;
    int eggs, dozens, leftover;
    double finalTotal;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number eggs needed>>");
    eggs= input.nextInt();
    dozens= eggs/dozen;
    leftOver= eggs%dozen;
    finalTotal= dozens*PricePerDozen+leftOver
*PricePerEgg;
    System.out.println("You order " + eggs + " eggs. That's " dozen and " dozen at $ " + PricePerDozen + " per dozen and " +leftOver +" loose eggs at " + (PricePerEgg*100) + " cents each for a total of $ " +finalTotal):
}
```

Im getting an error: expected unqualified-id for the line public static void main (string{}args). Not sure what's wrong as I'm new to c++ and coding in general.

The code is for this problem btw:

A farm sells eggs to local customer.  It charges $3.25 for a dozen eggs, or 45 cents for individual eggs that are not part of a dozen.

Write a program that prompts a user for the number of eggs in the order and then display the amount owed. (Declare the prices as constants)

---

Thanks for the replies, I'm new to this so I had no idea what I was doing but I corrected into proper c++ formatting. This is what I did instead:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
  int noOfEggs;
  const double pricePerDozen=3.25;
  const double pricePerEgg=0.45;
  double totalPrice;
  int noOfDozes,noOfLeftEggs;
  
  cout<<"How many eggs would you like?:";
cin>>noOfEggs;
  noOfDozes=noOfEggs/12;
  noOfLeftEggs=noOfEggs%12;
  
  totalPrice=(noOfDozes*pricePerDozen)+(noOfLeftEggs*pricePerEgg);
  cout<<noOfDozes<<" dozens and "<<noOfLeftEggs<<" eggs cost: $"<<totalPrice<<endl;
  return 0;
```

Comment: You can't just take Java code, and use it like c++, even if the syntax is similar. I suggest looking at examples from your textbook.

Comment: Java and C++ are two separate languages.  What you're doing is similar to taking a paragraph written in Spanish, changing some of the words to French, and think the paragraph is now French.

Comment: main can't be public because that only applies to class members.  It can't be static because you need external linkage (static means completely different things in Java and C++ as does volatile) Also, main can't be void - it has to return int.  The `[]` in a string array must appear after the name of the variable and has to have a number inside unless there is an initialiser.  And main doesn't take an array of strings as an argument anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This probably comes from the word `String` in the arguments to your `main()` function. There is no class, function, variable, etc. named `String` known to the compiler, so it gives an error. You'll probably get the same error from this program:

```
int main() {
    String s;
    return 0;
}
```

In this latter case, if you add a class named `String`, then you can get it to compile:

```
class String {};

int main() {
    String s;
    return 0;
}
```

As [cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372853/cigien) mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63985009/c-error-question-expected-unqualified-id#comment113145085_63985009), your code looks like Java code and is not valid C++, so you'll have a lot more things to fix before you can get it to compile. Fixing all those things is beyond the scope of this site. I just mentioned the likely cause of the one error you asked about.